# Rent Increase for Section 8 tenants

Tags: united-states, rental-property

We live on a property managed by a non-profit housing cooperation claiming to promote quality affordable housing. 
We receive Section 8 and when we moved here in 2008, the rent was $1110.00/month, and in December 2015, the rent was $1300.00/month.  Effective January 2016, management increased the rent to $1810.00/month.  Our share of the rent went up $500/month.  We've paid this months rent, but will not be able to pay next months rent without sacrificing two other monthly bills, since we are now paying about 70% of our gross monthly income for rent on a "affordable" housing property. Comparable apartments on the property are currently advertised for rent at $1500-$1600/month.  And, the neighboring rentals of much higher quality with more amentities, are cheaper than $1810.00/month.
I've called numerous state and federal housing offices trying to get help on what to do, and no one seems to have answers as they keep refering me to other offices.  Even the State Housing Authority that handles our Section 8 doesn't have answers.  Who can I call for help?

Comment: what country and state are you in?

Comment: Reference to Section 8 almost surely means the poster is in the USA.  I added country tag.

Comment: I'm not sure this really falls under personal finance, as your question is "who can I call for help?"  However, one possibility is to look up local rental housing mediation groups, tenants' associations, or legal aid offices.  Also, have you talked directly to your landlord (i.e., someone at the company that owns the apartment) to ask about this?

Comment: I know Section 8 rents can be raised but they must be approved and a 60 day notice given to the tenants. As for calling for help - the State Housing Authority is who you would need to get answers from - even if it is like pulling teeth.  I'm sure that department is about as efficient as the DVM system.

Comment: If your city has a 211 service, you can try calling them. It's free.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I am in the U.S..  I've called the State Housing Authority.  They say they don't know what can be done.  (Although they're the one who approved the increase) I plan to ask the property management how the increase makes it "affordable" for me based on my income. I also found there's a Renter's Protection Agency that handles complaints and the outcome is legally and binding.

Answer (score 2):

Section 8 tenants have an agent assigned to them. You said your share is now $500. This implies the agent approved this apartment. Something seems wrong here.

I am a Realtor, and have rented sec 8 apartments. We need to justify a price, typically by showing other identical units at the same price, or if not identical, a detailed explanation as to the difference.

I'd call the agent and get a recommendation on another apartment. We prefer to charge a fair price and keep a good reputation with the local section 8 office. Your landlord may not care.

Answer (score 0):

> TITLE 42 / CHAPTER 8 / § 1404a
>   42 USC 1404a: Secretary of Housing and Urban Development; right to sue; expenses
>   Text contains those laws in effect on March 21, 2016
>   From Title 42-THE PUBLIC HEALTH AND WELFARE
>   CHAPTER 8-LOW-INCOME HOUSING
>
> §1404a. Secretary of Housing and Urban Development; right to sue; expenses
>   The Secretary of Housing and Urban Development may sue and be sued only with respect to its functions under the United States Housing Act of 1937, as amended [42 U.S.C. 1437 et seq.], and title II of Public Law 671, Seventy-sixth Congress, approved June 28, 1940, as amended [42 U.S.C. 1501 et seq.]. Funds made available for carrying out the functions, powers, and duties of the Secretary of Housing and Urban Development (including appropriations therefor, which are authorized) shall be available, in such amounts as may from year to year be authorized by the Congress, for the administrative expenses of the Secretary of Housing and Urban Development. Notwithstanding any other provisions of law except provisions of law enacted after August 10, 1948 expressly in limitation hereof, the Secretary of Housing and Urban Development, or any State or local public agency administering a low-rent housing project assisted pursuant to the United States Housing Act of 1937 or title II of Public Law 671, Seventy-sixth Congress, approved June 28, 1940, shall continue to have the right to maintain an action or proceeding to recover possession of any housing accommodations operated by it where such action is authorized by the statute or regulations under which such housing accommodations are administered, and, in determining net income for the purposes of tenant eligibility with respect to low-rent housing projects assisted pursuant to said Acts, the Secretary of Housing and Urban Development is authorized, where it finds such action equitable and in the public interest, to exclude amounts or portions thereof paid by the United States Government for disability or death occurring in connection with military service.

I hope this helps you, i.e. the answer is you should call the above secretary.